# AJAX callback issue when using 'Manage Form Display' and 'Manage Display'

Tags: 8, ajax

Good day everyone,

So I have an issue that I haven't been able to google. The issue seems rather simple but I don't know what's causing it. When i'm managing field displays in either the form or a view, the ajax 'throbber' icon pops up and the ajax request is never completed. It will continue to show the throbber indefinitely. If I drag the field to another location, it will create another instance of the throbber icon and no ajax request is ever completed. I can do this any amount of times. When I save the form and a field is in the AJAX state, it just reverts back to whatever it was originally. The weird thing is, if I press the cog to change the settings of the field and that field was in the 'perpetual ajax request' state, it will then complete the ajax request as expected.

This leads me to believe that dragging and dropping the fields (and changing the formatter/widget) aren't actually sending any ajax requests. This is also confirmed by checking the Network tab in Chrome's tools. Nothing is sent when dragging fields but when pressing the cog "teaser?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax" request is sent.

I'm at a loss as to what is happening. It only started recently (last couple hours of development) and I went through the changes I've made in that time to try and identify the problem and have come up with nothing. I checked for differences from the production site and nothing... I'm not sure what to do next. Has anyone experienced this problem and successfully fixed it?

Comment: While you wait for a better answer, I recommend disabling Javascript in your browser. Drupal degrades gracefully, and should work fine without the AJAX drag-and-drop functionality. This _doesn't_ answer your question, but at least you can continue developing in the meantime. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this information. This may come in handy in the future, however, I did finally solve the issue. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel like a fool as the answer was actually simple... I had forgotten about switching all input elements to actual button elements. This broke any AJAX request only when the type was a submit button.